# Tabris UI Controls Demo Indication error on IPad and IPhone

Tags: eclipse-rap, tabris

I'm validating the Tabris framework at the moment and stumbled about a few indication errors when I tried the [UI Control Code Snippets](http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tabris/docs/ui-controls/).

I added the [VisualGuideDemo.java](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-demos/blob/master/com.eclipsesource.tabris.demos/src/com/eclipsesource/tabris/demos/entrypoints/VisualGuideDemo.java#L60) to my HelloWorld-Project and added a table to the display with the `createTable` function. In my browser it is displaying the expected output with 3 columns and 128 rows. When I test the application on an IPad mini or the IPhone Simulator ...

- only the first Column is displayed,
- it is not possible to scroll through the whole list (i can scroll about 60 items down, then the list "jumps" back)
- and the width of the table does not adjust to the fullwidth of the screen.

See attached Screenshots

[image: iphone simulator screenshot]
[image: ipad mini screenshot]

I also tried to add a TabFolder which uses the full width of the screen. I used the 'createTabFolder' method:

```
private void createTabFolder() {
  final Shell shell = new Shell( display, SWT.NONE );
  shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() );
  final TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder( shell, SWT.NONE );
  final TabItem tab0 = new TabItem( tabFolder, SWT.NONE );
  tab0.setText( "Tab0" );
  final TabItem tab1 = new TabItem( tabFolder, SWT.NONE );
  tab1.setText( "Tab1" );
  final TabItem tab2 = new TabItem( tabFolder, SWT.NONE );
  tab2.setText( "Tab2" );
  //shell.setSize( 300, 100 );
  shell.open();
}
```

I uncommented the setSize function, but the TabFolder does not adjust to the full width of the screen (not in browser or on iOS device).

I'm new to SWT, RAP/Tabris so I am wondering if I miss something basic.

EDIT:
I guess several columns in one table are not supported in the mobile clients, but maybe it would be a nice feature to add the missing columns to the end of the list, seperated by listdividers. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the width problem, I just had to call `shell.setMaximized(true);`